# SOAP Service Request

Tags: c#, soap, request

I have this code that tries to send a request to a soap server, I'm new to soap so i am not sure if the terms i am using are correct or not please correct me I am wrong.

Basically i am accessing a web service method named getUserDomain via soap request

Here is the code:

```
public void CallWebService()
{
    var _url = "https://....com/QcXmlWebService/QcXmlWebService.asmx?wsdl";
    var _action = "https://....com/QcXmlWebService/QcXmlWebService.asmx?op=GetUserDomains";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get the response from the completed web request.
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);
    }
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}

private XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
     string oRequest = "";
    oRequest = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:qcx=""http://smething.com/QCXML"">";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<soap:Header/>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<soap:Body>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<qcx:GetUserDomains>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<qcx:inputXml><![CDATA[";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<GetUserDomains>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<login>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<domain_name>MBB_BTS</domain_name>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<project_name>WCDMA_BTS_IV</project_name>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<user_name>user</user_name>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "<password>pass</password>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</login>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</GetUserDomains>";
    oRequest = oRequest + " ]]>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</qcx:inputXml>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</qcx:GetUserDomains>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</soap:Body>";
    oRequest = oRequest + "</soap:Envelope>";
    soapEnvelop.LoadXml(oRequest);
    return soapEnvelop;
}

private void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

This code i have seen somewhere in stack overflow before as an answer but i couldn't get it to work... The error I'm getting is threw exception System.net.webexception. the remote server returned an error :(500) internal server

Comment: Don't ever build XML by string concatenation. Is there a reason to not just use "Add Service Reference"?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1) click on Project->Add Service Reference
2) click on the "Advanced" button on the bottom of "Add Service Reference" Window
3) click on "Add Web Reference" button on the bottom of the "Service Reference Settings" window
4) type your URL in the URL bar to access the service.

No need for you to code all of that stuff. Once the service is added to your project, you can declare an instance of it and use it as needed.